# installing windows-sdk-10-version-2004-all fails reporting "was not successful. Exit code was '-2146889721'"

Tags: docker-for-windows, chocolatey

Installing windows-sdk-10-version-2004-all using chocolatey in docker with Dockerfile

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2019
RUN powershell.exe -NoProfile -InputFormat None -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "iex ((New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))" && SETX PATH "%PATH%;%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\chocolatey\bin" 
RUN choco install --no-progress -y windows-sdk-10-version-2004-all || ( type %ProgramData%\chocolatey\logs\chocolatey.log && type %TMP%\chocolatey\*.log )
```

It fails complaining

```
Hashes match.
Installing windows-sdk-10-version-2004-all...
ERROR: Running ["C:\Users\ContainerAdministrator\AppData\Local\Temp\chocolatey\windows-sdk-10-version-2004-all\10.0.19041.0\winsdksetup.exe" /Features + /Quiet /NoRestart /Log "C:\Users\ContainerAdministrator\AppData\Local\Temp\chocolatey\windows-sdk-10-version-2004-all_7076271d-d332-420d-94b9-c752a03907a4.log" ] was not successful. Exit code was '-2146889721'. See log for possible error messages.
```

Details of the error says:

```
[059C:08D4][2021-01-03T14:39:53]w343: Prompt for source of package: package_WPTx64_x86_en_us, payload: package_WPTx64_x86_en_us, path: C:\Users\ContainerAdministrator\AppData\Local\Temp\chocolatey\windows-sdk-10-version-2004-all\10.0.19041.0\Installers\WPTx64-x86_en-us.msi
[059C:08D4][2021-01-03T14:39:53]i000: package_WPTx64_x86_en_us
[059C:08D4][2021-01-03T14:39:53]i000: Resolving download root for: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?prd=11966&pver=1.0&plcid=0x409&clcid=0x409&ar=Windows10&sar=SDK&o1=10.0.19041.1
[059C:08D4][2021-01-03T14:39:53]i000: HTTP status code: 302
[059C:08D4][2021-01-03T14:39:53]i000: Redirected URL: https://www.microsoft.com?ref=go
[059C:08D4][2021-01-03T14:39:53]i000: Resolved redirected download root: https://www.microsoft.com?ref=go/
[059C:08D4][2021-01-03T14:39:53]i000: package_WPTx64_x86_en_us to https://www.microsoft.com/Installers/WPTx64-x86_en-us.msi
[059C:08D4][2021-01-03T14:39:53]i338: Acquiring package: package_WPTx64_x86_en_us, payload: package_WPTx64_x86_en_us, download from: https://www.microsoft.com/Installers/WPTx64-x86_en-us.msi
[082C:08B0][2021-01-03T14:39:53]e000: Error 0x80091007: Hash mismatch for path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\.unverified\package_WPTx64_x86_en_us, expected: 3F73CF1FD812D8877E1B9131E02D9ECBAA9EC773, actual: F21BF2F13F89D1C9DFD2844D57728102D5714EAA
```

This was running some weeks ago.

Is it possible to fix this check or ignoring it ?

Comment: It's a hash mismatch issue per the error for `package_WPTx64_x86_en_us`. Try running `Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /StartComponentCleanup`, then try the install again. If it fails again, it's either a download issue, an issue with chocolately, or the server contains a corrupted `package_WPTx64_x86_en_us` package _(if it's the latter, it has to be fixed on Microsoft's end)_. To rule out chocolately, try the install via the SDK [installer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk/) directly, which also supports a cli install.

Comment: @JW0914: installation on my PC works well, but it fails building docker image. Adding ` dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /StartComponentCleanup` also fails. Maybe link to the building plateform ?

Comment: I have no experience with docker, but am curious what error `Dism` returned

Comment: @JW0914 the error is not with `dism`, after executing it successfully, the `choco install` fails the same.

Comment: @JW0914: today the exact same docker build works, maybe packages changes....

Comment: Your previous comment implied the `Dism` command did fail, however if it occurs again, you may want to eliminate which component is the issue, chocolately or Microsoft's servers [first comment]

Comment: @JW0914 my comment was not enouph clear, the dism command did not fail, but executing it doesnot solve the problem and choco command fails the same. Now the chocolatey installation works,  probably something changes on sources.